# how to avoid sign error in symbolic integration

Tags: maxima

In the script below `gg(t)` is the standard `Gaussian` function, and `hh(u)` is its `Fourier` transform. I am calculating the energy both in `t` and `u` domains and try to verify that `wxmaxima (17.10.01)` gives the same. When calculating the energy in `u` domain the magnitude is correct `(the same as in 't', %o4)` but the sign is negative `(%o6)`, which is wrong. How can I avoid the error?

```
(%i1)   gg(t):=1/(σ*sqrt(2*%pi))*exp(-(t-t_0)^2/(2*σ^2));
(%o1)   gg(t):=1/(σ*sqrt(2*%pi))*exp((-(t-t_0)^2)/(2*σ^2))

(%i2)   ee(t):=exp(-%i*2*%pi*u*t);
(%o2)   ee(t):=exp((-%i)*2*%pi*u*t)

(%i3)   hh:integrate(gg(t)*ee(t), t, -∞,∞);
"Is "σ" positive or negative?"p;

(hh)    %e^(-2*%pi^2*u^2*σ^2-2*%i*%pi*t_0*u)

(%i4)   integrate(abs(gg(t))^2, t, -∞,∞);
"Is "σ" positive or negative?"p;
(%o4)   1/(2*sqrt(%pi)*σ)

(%i6)   kk:abs(hh)^2;
    integrate(kk, u, -∞,∞);
(kk)    %e^(-4*%pi^2*u^2*σ^2)
"Is "σ" zero or nonzero?"n;

(%o6)   -1/(2*sqrt(%pi)*σ)
 -->    ;
```

Comment: I can't confirm the error; for the last result I get `1/(2*sqrt(%pi)*σ)`. I am working with Maxima 5.41.0 + SBCL 1.3.14 + Ubuntu (x64). What does `build_info();` report? Maybe you can update your Maxima version.

Comment: @Robert _Dodier Sorry, I should have also said that I am using the windows version. Upon your suggestion I tried to update but unlike for the previous one I could not find the executable for the current version 18.02 on the website http://andrejv.github.io/wxmaxima/download.html . Do you know where is it? Thank you.

Comment: You can download Maxima from: https://sourceforge.net/projects/maxima/files/Maxima-Windows/5.41.0-Windows/ Note that wxMaxima is a user interface for Maxima, which is maintained as a separate project. It is probably more important to update the Maxima version -- the Maxima installation package includes wxMaxima, although perhaps not the most recent version.